# Entity Framework invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Id7S.png)The first i want to tell the problem appear when i publish my project to IIS Server and i found error like this. In local my project work fine.

> The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

and the connection String is:

```
connectionStrings>
<add name="imoney2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.registrasiFullModel.csdl|res://*/Models.registrasiFullModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.registrasiFullModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=**.**.**.**;user id=***;password=******;database=imoney2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="imoney2Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.RegisterFullModel.csdl|res://*/Models.RegisterFullModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.RegisterFullModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=**.**.**.**;user id=**;password=******;database=imoney2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Id7S.png)

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers></entityFramework>

Connection String in this line.

<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories></system.data>
```

Comment: Ensure you have `provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"` in web.config under `defaultConnectionFactory` section. Can you provide web.config details to help us check potential issues?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i want to give you the code but i can't insert in my question because there something error and i don't know so i edit and give photo about web config, are u have another idea? in my web.conf i already add provider like u said

Comment: Please avoid using images of code/exception error message because it is hard to reproduce; paste it as verbatim text instead. I want to know if you're using that provider inside web.config file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto edited sir. or if still can't maybe i can email u or something to give u the web.config

Comment: Since you're stated the code work in local but not in production, possibly you need to install MySQL Connector .NET (and MySQL Data Provider) inside production server. Ensure that the connector version exactly same as used in local dev machine.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the connector version already exactly same.

Comment: @JeremyPutra Check the Application Pool under which your website is running has `Enable 32 bit Application` set to true. Try after setting it to true